# How can i sequence for a range(5,10000) until it hits 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python and i am currently working on a task for my university. The question is the following:

Given that f(x) = x / 2 if x is even and f(x) = 3*x+1 if x is odd, how do i build a loop that picks a number from a range(5,10000) and sequences it for as long as if it hits 1, it stops. Right now i only accomplished that my loop sorts it in different lists. At least :D

This is my current code:

```
  odd = []
 even = []

for num in range (5,10000):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even.append(sum)
    else:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            odd.append(sum)
```

Comment: I don't get this part: `and sequences it for as long as if it hits 1, it stops` could you explain it in a different way?
Your code seems perfect for your task.

The code `range(5, 10000)` produces a list of numbers -> 5, 6, 7, 8, ... ,9999, maybe thats the source of your confusion?

Comment: You can make a small example and the expected answer based on that small sample to show the aim better

Comment: you don't need the `if num % 2 == 1` check, just the `else` by itself is enough (there are only two possible values for `num % 2`)

Answer (score 2):

This is famous math problem known as **Collatz conjecture** to make it simple we will perform the function 2*x if x is even and 3*x+1 if x is odd till it becomes 1. 1 is the minimum possible value of this sequence.

```py
import random
def collatz_sequence(x):
    seq = [x]
    if x < 1:
       return []
    while x > 1:
       if x % 2 == 0:
         x = x / 2
       else:
         x = 3 * x + 1
       seq.append(x)
    return seq

maxLength = -1
maxNum = 1
for num in range(5, 10001):
    currseq = collatz_sequence(num)
    print(currseq)
    currseq_len = len(currseq)
    if currseq_len > maxLength:
        maxLength = currseq_len
        maxNum = num
print(maxNum, maxLength)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how i can test for which number it takes the longest time until it hits 1? And also, it is possible to do this without the random.randint? I need the sequence for all numbers from 5 to 10000 :D

Comment: Yeah you mean in range(5,10000) which takes most time right?

Comment: yes! but if i try it with range it says :int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'range'

Comment: i am very impressed, thank you very much!! but why the maxLength = -1 and maxNum = 1 ? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: First we are assuming the maximum length it can be 1 also but as a habit I assigned it to -1 then we are comparing it and reassigning it in each step , similarly we are assigning the maxNum to 1, assuming 1 is the number with largest sequence then reassigning it to number with longest sequence hope it makes scence...

Comment: aahhh okay! i have 1 last question .. how to pop the last 3 numbers of each seq? I need to pop the last 3 of each seq and put them into a value = {} set

Comment: ```last_three = currseq[-3:]``` you can process the last_three further

Comment: `num` starting from `5` so it don't need to be test by `if x < 1`.

Comment: @Ali_Sh yeah that's right